# Transition/Moving an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a card game. I want to be able to pick two cards and make them move to the top of the screen so that I can see my selected options. Can somebody help me do this? P.S I am a beginner.

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this. For moving elements look into the 'ordinary' position e.g. top: property but more likely you will want to look at transform: translate... MDN is a reliable source of information.

Comment: .container {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: #ffffff;
box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(17, 1, 68, 0.08);
border-radius: 8px;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
}

Comment: These are the styles I have set for my cards - size and border. I would not like to be able to select them so user can see two selected options they chose and move those two cards to top of the screen.

Comment: Please read the link in my previous comment and put your code as a runnable snippet into your question, thanks.